# Moving from itext5 to itext7: How to replace a certain image inside a pdf?

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am just evaluating iText7 for a small tool we need to write about adding/replacing image-watermarks inside pdf files.

I could get the adding part to work with the samples from the official website but am struggeling about removing/replacing my added images.

There is an similar post for itext5 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308500

But I fail to adapt this to itext7 .. the API seems to have changed a lot and the official documentation is not very helpful either (or I just not find the right place to look at)

Basically I need to find my own added image from the pdf back which means to identify it either by an ID that I could give it during adding OR by identify it through its height/width (this would be unique enough for us).

Any help would be very welcome!

update

Code for adding the watermark (interesting might be how to mark the image to find it back easier later, but in general this works already fine):

```
var reader = new PdfReader($"c:\\testconv\\test.pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter($"c:\\testconv\\test+watermark.pdf"));

Rectangle pageSize;
PdfCanvas canvas;
int n = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

iText.IO.Image.ImageData myImageData = ImageDataFactory.Create($"c:\\testconv\\label@0,25x.jpg");

var height = 0.45f/2.54f*72f;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
    pageSize = page.GetPageSizeWithRotation();
    var top =  1.2f/2.54f*72f - height;
    var left = pageSize.GetWidth() - myImageData.GetWidth() / myImageData.GetHeight() * height - 1.2f / 2.54f * 72f;
    canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    canvas.AddImage(myImageData, left, top, height, false, false);
}
pdfDoc.Close();
```

for finding/removing the label again I dont have any working code really yet:

```
var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
var res = page.GetResources();
var xobj = res.GetResource(PdfName.XObject);

foreach (var xobject in xobj.KeySet())
{
    PdfObject obj = xobj.Get(xobject);
    if (obj.IsIndirect())
    {
        var stream = xobj.GetAsStream(xobject);
        var subtype = stream.GetAsName(PdfName.Subtype);
        if (PdfName.Image.Equals(subtype)) //direct image
        {

        }
        else if (PdfName.Form.Equals(subtype)) // check for nested image?
        {

        }                        
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to actually find the images and then compare their properties to find out if its the right or wrong one to delete (for example by a name or ID, or properties like width/height.

Comment: Please add the code you already have.

Comment: In particular do show the code you use to add the watermark.

Comment: thanks for the comments, please check my updated question to find the code I have so far.