# Why X/Y coordinators of image in pdf are always ZERO by GetImageCTM?

Tags: image, itext, coordinator-pattern

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. 
Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Any help will be appreciated.

I get the Matrix by ImageRenderInfo#GetImageCTM(), and get the X/Y coordiantors.
but it is always 0!

I have tried these api, GetStartPoint(), and GetImageCTM.
However, the X/Y coordinator is always 0 :-(

Note: I have some images in pdf in some positons(not the (0,0) coordinator).

```
void IRenderListener.RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo imgRenderInfo)
{
    Matrix mtx = imgRenderInfo.GetImageCTM();
    // x, y
    float[] coordinate = new float[] { mtx[Matrix.I31], mtx[Matrix.I32] };

    // Why the coordinate[0] and coordinate[1]
    // are always be ZERO regardless the positon in Pdf

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mkl 
I have got the coordinates by the [codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267309/programmatically-create-pdf-photo-albums/4316627?r=SearchResults#4316627)
`code`(
AcroFields fields = this.mReader.AcroFields;
PdfDictionary annots = fields.GetFieldItem(signatureName).GetMerged(0);
// rects are laid out [llx, lly, urx, ury]
float x, y, w, h;
PdfArray rect = annots.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
x = rect.GetAsNumber(0).FloatValue;
y = rect.GetAsNumber(1).FloatValue;
w = rect.GetAsNumber(2).FloatValue - x;
h = rect.GetAsNumber(3).FloatValue - y;)

Comment: Please don't use comments for such such extra information, instead [edit] your question to include them (there is a link underneath it). Code, in particular multi-line code, is virtually unreadable in comments.

Comment: But you are right, that determines the annotation rectangle coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer to the question as is

I parsed the page contents of an arbitrary file I had at hands (the example PDF from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55197143/1729265)) using a render listener with your implementation code plus output of the coordinates:

```cs
public void ExtractImageCoordinatesFromArchmodels()
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"EVERMOTION ARCHMODELS VOL.78.pdf"))
    {
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
        ImageCoordinatesRenderListener listener = new ImageCoordinatesRenderListener();
        for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            parser.ProcessContent(i, listener);
        }
    }
}

internal class ImageCoordinatesRenderListener : IRenderListener
{
    public void BeginTextBlock()
    { }

    public void EndTextBlock()
    { }

    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    { }

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        Matrix mtx = renderInfo.GetImageCTM();
        // x, y
        float[] coordinate = new float[] { mtx[Matrix.I31], mtx[Matrix.I32] };
        Console.WriteLine("Image at {0}, {1}.", coordinate[0], coordinate[1]);
    }
}
```

and the output was

```
Image at 6,00029, 52,15466.
Image at 19,84251, 363,4501.
Image at 294,091, 361,5604.
Image at 300,0336, 81,089.
Image at 15,59055, 72,94052.
Image at 5,322647, 340,7029.
Image at 288,5311, 386,0621.
Image at 291,7613, 69,35573.
Image at 28,50845, 53,13286.
Image at 41,2021, 380,3172.
Image at 290,8796, 368,9564.
Image at 295,8532, 50,71478.
Image at 19,13385, 49,21146.
Image at 25,5118, 385,9343.
Image at 282,4584, 379,8427.
Image at 293,5927, 65,19702.
Image at 4,535416, 60,35075.
Image at 3,364258, 374,4344.
Image at 288,0557, 373,5591.
Image at 299,9102, 59,13971.
Image at 11,33858, 66,10181.
Image at 11,66959, 380,3134.
Image at 297,1836, 378,4615.
Image at 299,9689, 66,74164.
Image at 10,62991, 53,18137.
Image at 5,180252, 377,7065.
Image at 279,9567, 377,9544.
Image at 289,9219, 69,23323.
Image at 6,400314, 68,17795.
Image at 11,33858, 361,2458.
Image at 297,1935, 373,4553.
Image at 299,8854, 68,30142.
Image at 7,086609, 68,13367.
Image at 3,82518, 352,3451.
Image at 287,9208, 373,4846.
Image at 294,6425, 68,3132.
Image at 41,2271, 68,15968.
Image at 5,709488, 356,2161.
Image at 304,9857, 373,593.
Image at 282,4557, 48,97745.
Image at 5,669281, 53,65367.
Image at 27,34265, 382,0123.
Image at 297,1409, 373,494.
Image at 300,0584, 50,23624.
Image at 7,245102, 68,23528.
Image at 8,503922, 380,1963.
Image at 290,1901, 355,9355.
Image at 287,2598, 60,53516.
Image at 5,102356, 68,01541.
Image at 17,00786, 378,9057.
Image at 296,8928, 373,5667.
Image at 299,9655, 68,04535.
```

(My locale uses a comma as decimal separator.)

So I cannot reproduce your claim

> the X/Y coordinator is always 0

Thus, what you observed is either due to some issue of your remaining code or something special about all your test PDFs; probably they simply indeed all have their images positioned at 0,0

#### Clarifications from comments

Meanwhile the OP has clarified in comments that the images of interest are located in *annotation* appearance streams, not in the *page* content stream.

Coordinates therein are in the respective annotation appearance stream coordinate system which is implied by the appearance's bounding box (its **BBox** entry). This bounding box then optionally is transformed by the appearance matrix (its **Matrix** entry). The resulting four sided area then is scaled and moved into the annotation's rectangle (its **Rect** entry). And depending on page rotation and annotation properties, this rectangle may be rotated by a multiple of 90° relative to the page coordinates.

Thus, a general solution transforming those coordinates into the default user space coordinate system of the page requires some math.

Often, though, bitmaps in annotation appearances are filling the bounding box (nearly) completely. Often there is no appearance matrix. And often annotations rotate with the page.

Thus, an often good approximation is to simply use the annotation rectangle. This also is what the OP now uses.

Comment: Thank u
I get the signature by PdfReader->AcroFields->GetSignatureNames(),loop the signature following (problem here?):
`code`
 PdfImageRenderListener lsr = new PdfImageRenderListener();
 PdfDictionary sDic = mReader.AcroFields.GetFieldItem(signature).GetMerged(0);
 PdfDictionary APDic = sDic.GetAsDict(PdfName.AP);
 PdfStream NStrm = APDic.GetAsStream(PdfName.N);
 PdfDictionary resDic = NStrm.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
 PdfContentStreamProcessor ps = new PdfContentStreamps(lsr); 
 ps.ProcessContent(ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesFromContentObject(NStrm), resDic);`code`

Comment: Please share an example pdf to reproduce the issue.

Comment: As an aside, though - when extracting information from an annotation appearance stream, you will obviously get coordinates in the coordinate system of that appearance stream. Thus, a 0,0 there has to be considered in context and may on the whole page be anywhere, depending on the annotation rectangle, stream boundary box, and stream matrix.

Comment: I use your [ExtractImageCoordinatesFromArchmodels] method, the coordinate is come out and not be ZERO. My extactor method by PdfContentStreamProcessor doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I can not share this production Pdf for security. But your extratctor by PdfReaderContentParser works well.
I want extact ONLY signature images and annotation images. Thanks for your response.

Comment: There are several images in every Page of pdf. I want to extact all signature images and annotation images with X/Y coordinates.

Comment: As mentioned above, images in annotations often indeed are at 0,0... *0,0 of the annotation appearance xobject*!

Comment: In the code in your comment you write `PdfContentStreamProcessor ps = new PdfContentStreamps(lsr);` - what class is `PdfContentStreamps`?

Comment: sorry [PdfContentStreamps] is PdfContentStreamProcessor's mistake.